# serverfault.daytorrents.com Phishing?

Tags: support

The origin `https://serverfault.daytorrents.com` is coming up in Google searches.

This site appears to be masquerading as serverfault.com, and is very convincing.

It has a valid HTTPS certificate and a login page.

Should I login?

Comment: If this is legitimate, I don't like it.  Allowing this type of mirroring could lead to confusion about who to trust on the Internet.

Comment: That site seems to be down now, but still showing up in some search results...

Comment: "Should I login?" - do you feel tempted?!

Comment: @DocRoot: The question was rhetorical.  As I understand it, sometimes people do get fooled by phishing attacks and, as I mentioned above, it's very convincing.  Everything appears normal except for the domain name -- and Google is still directing me there for certain searches.  There is definitely some bad stuff happening on that domain though.

Answer (score 6):

This short of thing should be reported to the company, there's an option in the Contact Us form specifically for reporting outside sites that are improperly using SE content.

In this case, I've just used the form to report it, so you don't need to.

Comment: From a user perspective, this problem could be much more urgent than "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" -- unless everyone understands this to mean that an active phishing attack is underway.

Comment: BTW: After you suggested this, I also reported with "Contact Us", and I tried to suggest greater urgency.  The site was down for a while, but it's back up right now.